Backpressure Problems in Spring Webflux: Can you help me understand what I'm missing in controlling flows? (Dropped Data OR Request Queue Full)
I am working on a personal project which I adapted from one of my school assignments to learn how to use and test Spring Webflux specifically. The problem was originally to migrate an entire database which should have large and unknown amounts of data. My focus here is how to create an asynchronous non-blocking solution using Spring Webflux. I figured that since this kinda problem has an unknown size set of data, it will force me to design proper solutions which can scale.
So that worked, and now I'm struggling with a problem that I think is due to backpressure based on the research I did to understand the problem using official documentation and other sources.
If anyone can help me understand what I'm doing wrong here, why it's wrong, and how I might fix it.
The problems
I had two specific problems which I think are related. I only have one of them at the time right now with my changes to avoid the first problem causing the second problem.
I think the core challenge in this part of the algorithm I am building order data which is built from data in multiple tables in the original database and requires reference to items in the new database.
Specifically, three database operations will cause streams when an order is migrated.

A list of Items from the old database related to this order to be converted and embedded as a list of items in the migrated order.
A payment from the old database to be embedded in the migrated order
A delivery from the old database to be embedded in the migrated order
A Customer from the new database to be referenced in the migrated order

Databases
I am using a Mysql database with the R2DBC driver as the source database, and a MongoDB database with the normal mongo reactive driver for the destination.
Problem 1: Request Queue Full
The original problem was that when I hit one of the larger the program would throw an exception "Request queue full". It was hard to trace exactly where this occurred, but I did isolate it to the largest and most complicated table migration, Orders.
Problem 2: Lost Data
My third solution during experimentation caused a lot of data to be lost after the procedure completes.
Probable causes.
1) Stream Depth
One Source  seemed to suggest it could be creating streams in streams. I didn't fully understand the problem here because that is how it's intended to be used since webflux should manage the streams and ordering. Though I can see how this can explode the number of streams.
2) The new streams are causing some sort of chain of requests that overwhelm the buffer
I didn't see something directly state this, but my reading on how streams work give me the impression this could be the case. I don't fully understand how  requests propagate through the chain of publishers.
3) Spring Data's Transaction Management
This was mentioned in the same place as stream depth. While I do have a good understanding of transactions at a conceptual level, I cannot say I fully understand how Spring Webflux implements transactions on a function that spans multile databases and it's implications on streams.
Code
MySqlToMongoMigration.java (Service)
    public Mono<Void> MigrateAll() {

        //Create publishers that can run in parallel
        return customerRepository.findAll()
                .flatMap(this::migrateCustomers)
                .checkpoint()
                .thenMany(
                        carrierRepository.findAll()

                )
                .flatMap(this::migrateCarriers)
                .checkpoint()
                .thenMany(
                        categoryRepository.findAll()
                )
                .flatMap(this::migrateCategories)
                .checkpoint()
                .thenMany(
                        supplierRepository.findAll()

                )
                .flatMap(this::migrateSuppliers)
                .checkpoint()
                .thenMany(
                        productRepository.findAll()
                )
                .flatMap(this::migrateProducts)
                .checkpoint()
                .thenMany(
                        ordersRepository.findAll()
                )
//                .checkpoint()
                .flatMap(this::migrateOrders,err->{
                    log.error(err);
                    return Mono.empty();
                },null)//Migrate all orders
                .then(); //Return void publisher that sends signals when process is done.


    }

    /**
     * Migrate a customer from Mysql DB to Mongo DB
     * @param sqlCx The Customer to be migrated
     * @return A publisher for the customer after migration
     */
    @Transactional
    Mono<MongoCustomer> migrateCustomers(MySqlCustomer sqlCx) {
        ArrayList<String> contacts = new ArrayList<>(List.of(sqlCx.getContacts().split(" ")));
        MongoCustomer mongoCustomer = MongoCustomer.builder()
                .name(sqlCx.getName())
                .contacts(contacts)
                .legacyId(sqlCx.getId())
                .build();
        return mongoCustomerRepository.save(mongoCustomer);
    }

    /**
     * Migrate a Carrier from Mysql DB to Mongo DB
     *
     * @param sqlCarrier The Carrier to be migrated
     * @return A publisher for the carrier after migration
     */
    @Transactional
    Mono<MongoCarrier> migrateCarriers(MySqlCarrier sqlCarrier) {
        ArrayList<String> contacts = new ArrayList<>(List.of(sqlCarrier.getContacts().split(" ")));
        MongoCarrier mongoCarrier = MongoCarrier.builder()
                .legacyId(sqlCarrier.getId())
                .name(sqlCarrier.getName())
                .contacts(contacts)
                .build();
        return mongoCarrierRepository.save(mongoCarrier);
    }

    /**
     * Migrate a Category from Mysql Db to Mongo DB
     *
     * @param mySqlCategory The Mysqlcategory to be migrated
     * @return A publisher for the category after migration
     */
    @Transactional
    Mono<MongoCategory> migrateCategories(MySqlCategory mySqlCategory) {
        MongoCategory mongoCategory = MongoCategory.builder()
                .legacyId(mySqlCategory.getId())
                .description(mySqlCategory.getDescription())
                .build();
        return mongoCategoryRepository.save(mongoCategory);
    }

    /**
     * Migrate a Supplier from Mysql Db to Mongo DB
     *
     * @param mySqlSupplier The mysql supplier to be migrated
     * @return A publisher for the  supplier after migration
     */
    @Transactional
    Mono<MongoSupplier> migrateSuppliers(MySqlSupplier mySqlSupplier) {
        ArrayList<String> contacts = new ArrayList<>(List.of(mySqlSupplier.getContacts().split(" ")));
        MongoSupplier mongoSupplier = MongoSupplier.builder()
                .legacyId(mySqlSupplier.getId())
                .name(mySqlSupplier.getName())
                .contacts(contacts)
                .build();
        return mongoSupplierRepository.save(mongoSupplier);
    }

    /**
     * Migrate a product from Mysql Db to Mongo DB
     *
     * This function requires that both Category and Suppliers have been migrated.
     *
     * @param mysqlProduct The product being migrated
     * @return A reactive stream that includes the converted product.
     */
    @Transactional
    Mono<MongoProduct> migrateProducts(MySqlProduct mysqlProduct) {
        return Mono.zip(
                mongoCategoryRepository.findByLegacyId(mysqlProduct.getCategory()),
                mongoSupplierRepository.findByLegacyId(mysqlProduct.getSupplier())
        )
                .map(tuple -> MongoProduct.builder()
                    .legacyId(mysqlProduct.getId())
                    .price(mysqlProduct.getPrice())
                    .description(mysqlProduct.getDescription())
                    .category(tuple.getT1())
                    .supplier(tuple.getT2())
                    .build()
                )
                .flatMap(product -> mongoProductRepository.save(product));
    }

    /**
     * Migrate an Order including its associated delivery, payment, and items to Mongo DB
     *
     * Dependency: This requires all Customers, Products, Carriers, and Deliveries are in MongoDB
     * @param mySqlOrders The mysqlorder to be migrated
     * @return A publisher that returns the migrated order
     */
    @Transactional
    Mono<MongoOrders> migrateOrders(MySqlOrders mySqlOrders) {
        return Mono.just(MongoOrders.builder()
                .legacyId(mySqlOrders.getId())
                .totalPrice(mySqlOrders.getTotalPrice())
                .date(mySqlOrders.getDate())
                .saleDate(mySqlOrders.getSaleDate())
                .build())
                .zipWith(
                        itemRepository.findByOrders(mySqlOrders.getId())
                                .log()
                                .flatMap(this::convertItem)
                                .collectList()
                )
                .checkpoint()
                .map(tuple ->{
                    MongoOrders o = tuple.getT1();
                    o.setItems(tuple.getT2());
                    return o;
                })
                .zipWith(
                        paymentRepository.findById(mySqlOrders.getPayment())
                                .log()
                                .flatMap(this::convertPayment)
                )
                .map(tuple ->{
                    MongoOrders o = tuple.getT1();
                    o.setPayment(tuple.getT2());
                    return o;
                })
                .zipWith(
                        deliveryRepository.findById(mySqlOrders.getId())
                                .log()
                                .flatMap(this::convertDelivery)
                )
                .map(tuple -> {
                    MongoOrders o  = tuple.getT1();
                    o.setShipment(tuple.getT2());
                    return o;
                })
                .zipWith(
                        mongoCustomerRepository.findByLegacyId(mySqlOrders.getId())
                                .log()
                )
                .map(tuple -> {
                    tuple.getT1().setCustomer(tuple.getT2());
                    tuple.getT1().setCustomerName(tuple.getT2().getName());
                    return tuple.getT1();
                })
                .flatMap(order -> mongoOrdersRepository.save(order).log());
    }

    /**
     * Converts an item from MysqlItem to a MongoItem. The item is converted
     * but not saved to the database.
     * This requires the associated MongoProduct to exist.
     *
     * @param item The MySql item that will be converted
     * @return A Publisher that will return the converted item
     */
    @Transactional
    Mono<MongoItem> convertItem(MySqlItem item) {
        return mongoProductRepository.findByLegacyId(item.getProduct())
                .log()
                .map(
                        product -> MongoItem.builder()
                                .legacyId(item.getId())
                                .price(product.getPrice())
                                .description(product.getDescription())
                                .quantity(item.getQuantity())
                                .product(product)
                                .build()
                );

    }


    /**
     * Converts a Mysqlpayment into a MongoPayment which can be embedded into an order. It will not
     * save this MongoPayment into the database.
     *
     * @param mySqlPayment The Mongo payment to be converted
     * @return A publisher that will return the converted MongoPayment
     */
    @Transactional
    Mono<MongoPayment> convertPayment(MySqlPayment mySqlPayment) {
        return Mono.just(MongoPayment.builder()
                .id(mySqlPayment.getId())
                .paymentDate(mySqlPayment.getPaymentDate())
                .build()
                );
    }

    /**
     * Converts a Delivery from a MysqlDelivery into a MongoDelivery which can be embedded
     * into an order. It will not save this delivery to the mongo database.
     * Dependency: Mongo Carrier associated with delivery must be in the mongo database.
     * @param mySqlDelivery The delivery to be converted
     * @return A publisher that will return the complete MongoDelivery
     */
    @Transactional
    Mono<MongoDelivery> convertDelivery(MySqlDelivery mySqlDelivery) {
        return mongoCarrierRepository.findByLegacyId(mySqlDelivery.getCarrierId())
                .log()
                .map(
                        carrier -> MongoDelivery.builder()
                                .legacyOrderId(mySqlDelivery.getOrderId())
                                .carrier(carrier)
                                .deliveryDate(mySqlDelivery.getDeliveryDate())
                                .build()
                );

    }


}

MySqlToMongoMigrationTest.java
@Test
    public void fullMigrationTest() {
        mySqlToMongoMigration.MigrateAll()
                .thenMany(mongoOrdersRepository.count())
                .as(StepVerifier::create)
                .assertNext(c -> Assertions.assertEquals(12000,c))
                .verifyComplete();
    }


The first thing I tried was to use  .onBackpreassureBuffer() and .limitRate() to potentially handle the case where streams are creating too many requests. This didn't seem to have any impact and some searching seemed to indicate that it's use is not reliable because some publishers will not honour it. I do not know if that was my case.
The second thing I tried was to create a strict chain by using .zipWith(), Flux.zip(),.thenMany() to coordinate the chain of streams for each element.

This would slow my original plan where I allowed things to run concurrently unless there was a dependency. Where there was a dependency, I originally used Zipwith when making that stream so that it waited on the previous ones to finish before it continued.

The third thing I tried was to remove @transactional. After this, the Request Queue error didn't occur in the test. However, I did notice that only 400 of 12000 elements were converted successfully. This gives me problem 2 which I think was caused by a default behavior in backpressure where it drops elements when there is too much backpressure. When I did this with onBackpreassureBuffer() on or off I got the same result.

I would appreciate If anyone can help me understand what I'm doing wrong here, why it's wrong, and how I might fix it.
